# @ResponseStatus and @ResponseBody not working with @ExceptionHandler

Tags: spring, exception, gson

I tried to implement a `@ControllerAdvice` to globally handle some general exceptions related to my web application. I wanted to send a wrapped JSON response with response status set accordingly. Here is a code sample.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalErrorHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public Response handleAllErrors() {
        Response wrapped = new Response(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "error");
        wrapped.setMessage("Could not retrieve data");
        return wrapped;
    }
}
```

`Response` is a POJO used to wrap the response. The problem is, despite the `@ResponseStatus` annotation, the response always has status code 500 (Internal Server Error) with the default error page showing the stack trace. Even the `@ResponseBody` seems not to work. But the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler) states that I could send a JSON response on an `@ExceptionHandler` method. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong in here.

I'm using Spring 3.2.8 release framework and Gson is used for message conversion, if that matters.

Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Can the Controllers extend from the GlobalErrorHandler?

Comment: Why should they? @ControllerAdvice is used to handle any exception that is not handled by a controller

Comment: Fair enough, wasn't sure about that annotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the issue. It was because all the getters and setters of the Response POJO were not defined.

Comment: GOD F**** BLESS YOU. I have been 3 hours searching for the solution. I wish I could give you +10000